# Adjusting Binary Logistic Formula in SPSS

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, adjustment

I am running a binary logistic regression in SPSS, to test the effect of e.g. TV advertisements on the probability of a consumer to buy a product. My problem is that with the formula of binary logistic regression:

```
P=1/(1+e^(-(a+b*Adv)) )
```

the maximum probability will be equal to 100%. However,even if I increase the number of advertisements by 1000, it is not sensible to assume that the probability to purchase will be 100%. So if I draw the graph of the logistic regression with the coefficients from the Binary Logistic Regression, at some point the probability reaches 100%, which is never the case in a real life setting. How can I control for that?

Is there a way to change the SPSS binary logistic regression to have a maximum probability of e.g. 20%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the predicted probability will never become exactly 100%, just increasingly close to it.

In practice every model will give you ridiculous predictions if you extrapolate far enough, so the trick is to not extrapolate too much rather than fix the model. After all, how can you fix a model for problems in an area where you have no data?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Well you are right about extrapolating too far, but imagine that you have to show results to clients and be able to back them up.

What I was thinking is that if you change the denominator of the formula:

2+e^(-(a+b*Adv))

then the probability will never surpass 50%. So for instance by discussing with managers, you can speculate that the maximum probability that could be reached by increasing advertising indefinitely, could be e.g. 50%.
But I do not know if it is possible to change something in the binary logistic regression in SPSS in order to achieve this.

Comment: Just present your results for the range you have data on. Your clients are smart enough to understand that you cannot say things about stuff you haven't seen. Making the model more complicated typically won't make your results easier to communicate, so I would not go in that direction.

Comment: Yes I think I will have to go this way then. But usually, I thought that modelling is useful for forecasting and not basing the insights only on data that you have available. In such a scenario I would have to conclude that the forecasting ability of my model is under-performing. To sum up, it is very interesting to see what happens with values that do not appear in your dataset. In any case thank you and sorry for my many questions, but I am a beginner on data modelling.

Comment: Extrapolating a tiny bit can be interesting, but a model is not a cristal ball. Information has to come from somewhere: if you have data on what happens between 0 and 5 adds, you might cautiously look at what the model predicts for 6 or 7 adds, but you just have no way of knowing what will happen when you look at a 1000 adds (my prediction would be severe brain damage resulting in an inability to buy anything...)